# How do I calculate the sum of 2 columns, using the max from each row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have data in two columns.  I would like the sum of the two columns, using the maximum value for each row.

For instance

```
C1  C2
 1   2
 4   3
11      
    10
 5   7
```

The result would be 2+4+11+10+7.

I would prefer if the solution worked in Google Spreadsheets, but if that can't happen Excel would be ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a one cell solution you can use an "array formula" like this in excel

`=SUM(IF(A2:A6>B2:B6,A2:A6,B2:B6))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

In google docs you should be able to do the same - either use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER with the above  or use

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(A2:A6>B2:B6,A2:A6,B2:B6)))`

Answer (score 1):

Is this too simple?

```
C1  |C2   |C3
1   |2    |=MAX(A2,B2)
4   |3    |=MAX(A3,B3)
11  |     |=MAX(A4,B4)
    |10   |=MAX(A5,B5)
5   |7    |=MAX(A6,B6)
    |     |=SUM(C2:C6)
```

Comment: Looks good.  If no one posts a one-cell answer I'll accept.